# Get listed in Google Drive Apps Collection

Tags: google-drive-api

I have released an app for Google Drive in the Chrome Web Store. I thought it might get added to the Google Drive Collection automatically, but that didn't happen. Is there any form I have to submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your application to appear in [the collection of Drive apps](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/collection/drive_apps) your Chrome Web Store app's manifest file need to specify the Google Drive container and your API console project ID as described in [this document](https://developers.google.com/drive/listing).

Then your app's listing should get the "Works with Google Drive" badge and, given a few minutes delay for indexing, your app will appear on [the collection of Drive apps](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/collection/drive_apps).

Beware: **you may not see it there** as a listing doesn't appear for you in that collection if you have already installed it on your browser. It will appear to all other users who have not installed your app yet. To make sure it's there: try looking at the collection with another browser (FireFox for instance).

Comment: Tom, perhaps you could share the link to your app's Chrome Web Store listing and I can tell you if I see it in the Drive collection. Alternatively try looking at the collection with another browser (FireFox for instance) as it won't appear in the collection if you have installed the app on your Chrome (i.e. if the app appears in the New Tab page)

Comment: Thanks @Nivco! The app I'm talking about is "OpenOffice Document Reader": https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jpcfmmdlhndnfpagbmhbbfehenapoich

Comment: I confirm it's in the list :)
Thanks for integrating with Google Drive!